# How Do I Prevent an HTTPS Redirect Loop in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, https, url-rewriting, config

My colleague and I have been through several stackoverflow posts and other articles but cannot figure out why we are still getting a redirect loop. We are new to NGINX, so we have a feeling there is something wrong with our config file.

Our thinking in the following code is as follows:

1. The first block removes the www from the request.
2. The second block listens on port 80 and if the request is http://example.org/test11 then redirect to https://example.org/test11.
3. The third block sees the request come in over 443 and handles it.

What are we overlooking here?

```html
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name www.site.org;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.org/$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.org;
  root /home/site/sites/example.org;

  if ($scheme = http){
     rewrite ^/test11$ https://example.org/test11 redirect;
  }

  rewrite ^/member$ /members permanent;
  rewrite ^/system$ /system/index.php permanent;

  location / {
    index index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @ee;
  }

  location @ee {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?$1 last;
  }

  location ~ /.git {
    deny all;
  }

real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.org;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cert.key;
  root /home/site/sites/example.org;
}
```

Comment: What request causes redirect loop?

Comment: For example, http://example.org/test11 will cause a redirect loop.